# how to classify highly overlapping data after PCA and t-SNE?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, class-imbalance, pca

I'm working on a classification (3 classes) of unbalanced weather data having 22 features. Even after applying PCA and t-SNE the data is overlapping. The best classification score achieved so far is using the tree-based method. What can be the reason for such PCA plot and what techniques I can implement to get more than 80% accuracy? [image: pca plot][image: y-sne plot]

Comment: It could be that your features are not terribly predictive of the outcome. [Worth reading…](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/how-to-know-that-your-machine-learning-problem-is-hopeless)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use UMAP. It is a superior algorithm to both of them:

- YOUTUBE: [UMAP explained | The best dimensionality reduction?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BPl81wGGP8)
- Publication: [UMAP: Uniform Manifold Approximation and Projection for Dimension Reduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426)
- Guide: [How to Program UMAP from Scratch](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-program-umap-from-scratch-e6eff67f55fe)
- CODE: [GitHub - NikolayOskolkov/HowUMAPWorks: Here I explain the math behind UMAP and show how to program it from scratch in Python](https://github.com/NikolayOskolkov/HowUMAPWorks)
- [Official Library](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap)